# What is use of getFacetedData() in Magento 2?

Tags: magento2, collection

Can any please explain use of `getFacetedData()` is Magento 2 with collection

Answer (score 5):

`getFacetedData` only exists in the product "fulltext" collection, i.e. for search results and category pages.

It returns information for the layered navigation, as returned by the search engine (MySQL, ElasticSearch, or custom implementation).

For each of these, it contains the number of results:

- price ranges
- categories
- filterable attributes

Comment: Aggree with you. Now my question is : $productionCollecyionData->getFacetedData('category') gives me value, count array  based on category. But does not give correct result if product has been assigned to multiple category.